# Why I cannot see network shares on nautilus?

Tags: 12.04, samba, file-sharing

I'm running Ubuntu 12.04.

I'm not able to see my workgroup and network shares when clicking on `Browse network` in nautilus. This is very important for my work.

I can access Windows and Ubuntu folders typing `nautilus smb://192.168.x.x` in the terminal. A windows PC can access Ubuntu's shares.

`smbtree` doesn't give anything.

Comment: You must give nautilus some time for those things. Try to look for network issues. Is the homeserver running? password protection Disabled?

Comment: My network seems fine (windows pc can access the ubuntu's shared folders; no firewall). In my smb.conf password protection is like this: "; encrypt passwords = yes". I'm not sure what is the homeserver.

Comment: Nautilus drove me crazy for a couple hours, the results were switching to Dolphin everything just works.
Dolphin FTW!!!